# How to fix height of Community box CSS in different browser

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, browser, height

Height for the Community Box looks different at firefox browser compared to Chrome. How do I fix it? http://sciex.com/support

```
<div class="row"><!--   SECTON PROMO  -->
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
<div><header><a class="promo-1153" href="community">Community</a></header>
<div style="height: 224px;">
  <h2 style="padding: 15px;">Frequently Asked Questions:</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>What should I do if Analyst freezes and won&rsquo;t respond to any commands?</a></li>
    <li>XIC Manager isn&rsquo;t working with multi-period data files, what should I do?</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you would require js to do this in your layout: [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dkokkcom/1/)

```
var hRight = $('.right').height();
$('.left').height(hRight);
```

Answer (score 1):

< div class="callout" > has set

```
.feature-callout-combo .callout {
    min-height: 274px;
}
```

which doesn't work for some reason in FF, but only on the Community box. For Library it does indeed work, because disabling it lessens its height...
If you instead use height: 274px, it works perfectly fine. Which should not be a solution tbh, it's rather an ugly hack.
Overall this seems like a bug to me? Have no time left sadly, maybe you can find out something with this.